# How to store 1e100 number in java (like python example)?

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers

I need to output: `yes` if `N` is a direct power of `2` and `no` otherwise, where `1 <= N <= 1e100`

Same in **Python** code:

```
n=int(input())
if(n!=0 and (n&(n-1)==0)):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to store arbitrarily large integers.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(sc.nextLine());
if(!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) && n.and(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
   System.out.println("yes");
} else {
   System.out.println("no");
}
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/DSE0iI)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you have to use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class for integers this big. This class also has several convenient methods to work with the binary representation of this number.

For example, you can use `bitCount` to determine if number is a power of 2:

```
boolean isPowerOf2(BigInteger integer) {
    return integer.bitCount() == 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
var integer = new BigInteger("1267650600228229401496703205376");
if (isPowerOf2(integer)) System.out.println("yarp");
else System.out.println("nope");
```